# Can't boot Debian after force EFI installation

Tags: linux, debian, boot, grub, uefi

I just installed Debian with encrypted `/`, I made a `/boot` partition and converted an NTFS partition to EFI, it installed but now I can't boot on linux. My motherboard boot list put a mirrored "N" sign like the russian letter and when I try to boot on it nothing happens. I can add that the NTFS partition that I converted to EFI ESP during installation is still around with data intact and NTFS format (accessible from windows 10, it contains windows 10 booting files).

Any idea ?

Thanks.

The partitioning layout is : 500MB NTFS that i tried to convert to EFI USP, 370 NTFS, 104 Encrypted /, 1gb /boot

Comment: Are you dual booting win/*nix ? make sure you are not in legacy mode "from bios menu" !! can you share what are your partitions (et4 , home , ....)look like ?

Comment: How are you partitioning  i.e  gparted?

Comment: @NullSoulException partitioning through the debian installer software. It's on an SSD I believe it's GPT partitionning but I can't make more than 4 primary and GRUB command line says (hd1,msdos1) so I'm not sure how to interprete that. (I could access GRUB on the first debian when I didn't force EFI install, this thread is about a reinstallation where I forced EFI install)